# Is it possible to control rfid buzzer by RS-232 serial in raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, rfid

I'm trying to control (**enable/disable**) **the buzzer** of my UHF RFID Reader (CT-I809) by **RS-232 serial** port in raspberry pi with **python**. My app works well in detecting RFID tag, but when i click the "STOP READING" button, the buzzer is still buzzing and I feel it's so annoying.

Below is how my RFID Reader looks like.

[image]
[image]

I have found a Windows app that is able to control it, but it was in C#. I try to open it in my raspberry pi (OS Raspbian) with mono, but it failed because the app use native windows dll SDK. So, I decided to write my own app in python and here is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import threading, serial, binascii

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "COM1"
# ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.baudrate = 57600
ser.timeout = None
header = "00ee00"
epc = []
count = []
index = 0

class AppBase(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.initialize_user_interface()

    def initialize_user_interface(self):
        self.parent.title("COMEL Reader")
        self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        title = ttk.Label(self.parent, text="COMEL Reader", font=("Arial 20 bold"))
        title.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.read_btn = tk.Button(self.parent, text="READ", state=tk.NORMAL, height=2, width=10,
        command=self.switch)
        self.read_btn.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.E, padx=10)

        # Set the treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.parent,
        columns=('TagID', 'Count'))
        self.tree.grid(padx=10, pady=10)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='No.')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='TagID')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='Count')
        self.tree.column('#0', width=40, stretch=tk.YES)
        self.tree.column('#1', width=200, stretch=tk.YES)
        self.tree.column('#2', width=100, stretch=tk.YES, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.grid(row=4, columnspan=4, sticky='nsew')

        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        vsb.place(x=335, y=90, height=202)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        self.treeview = self.tree

        self.i = 0
        self.active = False

        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.parent, mode='indeterminate')
        self.progressbar.grid(column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.E)

    def switch(self):
        global index
        if self.active == True:
            self.active = not self.active
            self.read_btn["text"] = "READ"
            ser.close()
        else:
            self.treeview.delete(*self.treeview.get_children())
            index = 0
            self.i = 0
            epc.clear()
            count.clear()
            self.read_btn["text"] = "STOP"
            self.active = not self.active
            ser.open()
            self.start_submit_thread(None)

    def read_tag(self):
        global index
        global count

        while self.active == True:
            if self.active == False:
                break
            ser.flushInput() 
            read_result = ser.read(8)
            hex_string = binascii.hexlify(read_result).decode('utf-8')
            data = hex_string[hex_string.index(header) + len(header):].upper()
            if "B0" not in data:
                continue
            else:
                if index==0:
                    self.i = self.i + 1
                    epc.append(data)
                    count.append(1)
                    self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text=str(self.i),
                                        values=(epc[index],
                                        str(count[index])))
                    index = index + 1
                else:
                    if data in epc:
                        data_index = epc.index(data)
                        count[data_index] = count[data_index]+1
                        x = self.treeview.get_children()[data_index]
                        self.treeview.item(x,
                                values=(epc[data_index],
                                str(count[data_index])))
                    else:
                        self.i = self.i + 1
                        epc.append(data)
                        count.append(1)
                        self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text=str(self.i),
                                            values=(epc[index],
                                            str(count[index])))
                        index = index + 1

    def start_submit_thread(self,event):
        self.submit_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.read_tag)
        self.submit_thread.daemon = True
        self.progressbar.start()
        self.submit_thread.start()
        root.after(20, self.check_submit_thread)

    def check_submit_thread(self):
        if self.submit_thread.is_alive():
            root.after(20, self.check_submit_thread)
        else:
            self.progressbar.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=tk.Tk()
    AppBase(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I also have decompiled the C# SDK, but for me it's too complex, here is some code:

```
if(lstrcmpA(lpProcName,"Writebaud")==0)
    return (FARPROC)UHFReader18_RVA(0x4570);
if(lstrcmpA(lpProcName,"SetPowerDbm")==0)
    return (FARPROC)UHFReader18_RVA(0x4830);
if(lstrcmpA(lpProcName,"BuzzerAndLEDControl")==0)
    return (FARPROC)UHFReader18_RVA(0x4920);
```

and from header file:

```
void* __stdcall UHFReader18_RVA(DWORD rvaAddr);
```

Back to my question, is it possible to control the buzzer of RFID reader by serial in python? Every answer will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you please show some code of what you already did? Thanks

Comment: Can you also provide the documentation of the buzzer? My guess is that you are sending the wrong command.

Comment: I have edit my question. Thank you for responding.